# How to make a "Service temporarily not available" page with a backdoor?

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

After tests are done in a test environment, we are trying to test our server in a real environment for a final test. But only devs must be accessible its features during the test period. How to do this?

My idea is using an interceptor like this:

- All requests are redirected to "Service temporarily not available" page and session will be invalidated. Except:
- Specified request IPs can bypass this.
- Requests with the correct backdoor password in the URL parameter or cookie can bypass this.
- After a successful bypass using a password, the password is saved as a short life cookie.
- Wrong or none password included requests' cookie will be removed.
- After tests are done, the interceptor is removed.
- Maybe it can be reused with a different password afterward.

But is this a good idea? Are there better approaches?

Comment: These ideas describe what Spring Security does. You can have a profile-based security or role configuration that will allow you to configure that only devs have access to certain endpoints.

Comment: Spring Security can do access for certain whitelisted IP-addresses or use feature toggles (for instance [Togglz](https://www.togglz.org)).